# jQuery - Show loading symbol when changing option from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I'm having the following select menu:

```
<select name="period" id="stats-period">
        <option value="all">All time</option>
        <option value="360">12 months</option>
        <option value="270">9 months</option>
        <option value="180">6 months</option>
        <option value="90">3 months</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="30">30 days</option>
        <option value="7">7 days</option>
    </select>
```

When I select an option from the dropdown I do an ajax call in order to get the correct records from database, so this is my script:

```
function timePeriod(changePeriod) {

                var url = '<?= admin_url('reports/change_period') ?>';

                $.post(url, {period: changePeriod}, function (response) {

                    var json = $.parseJSON(response);

                    if (json.error == true) {
                        $('#reports').hide();
                        $('#no-reports').show();
                    } 
                    else {
                        $('#reports').show();
                        $('#no-reports').hide();

                        $('#numprojects').text(json.projects);
                        $('#average-cost').text(json.average_cost.toFixed(2));
                        $('#over-budget').text(json.over_budget);
                        $('#average-client-flags').text(json.average_client_flags);
                        $('#average-delayed').text(json.average_delayed.toFixed(1));
                    }
                });
            }

            $('#stats-period').on('change', function(){
                var selected = $(this).val();
                timePeriod(selected);
            });
```

What I wan't to do is to show a loading symbol when changing the selected value of the dropdown, until the ajax call is completed, How can I do this?

Comment: Show the symbol when the user activates your dropdown, and hide it in the Ajax callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your loading gif is inside a div with ID = `#myDiv`

```
function timePeriod(changePeriod) {

    var url = '<?= admin_url('reports/change_period') ?>';

    $('#myDiv').show();

    $.post(url, {period: changePeriod}, function (response) {

        $('#myDiv').hide();

        var json = $.parseJSON(response);

        >SNIP<
```

Comment: How can I set it on top of the div I want to display the data? is it something I can do it with jquery, or use plain css??

Comment: Pure CSS. That is a couple of things: (1) `position:absolute` so you can position the DIV using `top:88px` and `left:88px`, and also (2) `z-index:99` to place that div on top of the other elements *(Note: the numbers used in these examples are examples - make the numbers whatever is appropriate)*

Answer (score 0):

Display the loading symbol at the beginning of the function that will do the Ajax call. And remove the loading symbol inside the `success:` of the Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the loading element if it isn't exists yet, show position it relatively to your select option. Once you get the response from the server you can hide it:

```
function timePeriod(changePeriod) {
    var url = '<?= admin_url('reports/change_period') ?>';
    if ($('#loading').length == 0) {
        loading = $('<img src="loading.gif" alt="" id="loading" />')
        $('body').append(loading)
        loading.hide();
    } else {
        loading = $('#loading');
    }
    loading.position({
      my: "left top",
      at: "right top",
      of: "#stats-period"
    }).show();
    $.post(url, {period: changePeriod}, function (response) {
        loading.hide();

        var json = $.parseJSON(response);
        if (json.error == true) {
            $('#reports').hide();
            $('#no-reports').show();
        } 
        else {
            $('#reports').show();
            $('#no-reports').hide();

            $('#numprojects').text(json.projects);
            $('#average-cost').text(json.average_cost.toFixed(2));
            $('#over-budget').text(json.over_budget);
            $('#average-client-flags').text(json.average_client_flags);
            $('#average-delayed').text(json.average_delayed.toFixed(1));
        }
    });
}

$('#stats-period').on('change', function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    timePeriod(selected);
});
```